# Very slow indexing in Pandas 0.15 compared to 0.13.1

Tags: python, pandas

I use pandas daily in my work. I recently upgraded to 0.15.1 from 0.13.1 and now a bunch of code is too slow to finish when iterating through relatively small DataFrames.

(I realize there are often better/faster ways to accomplish iteration on a DataFrame, but sometimes it's very clear and succinct to have a for loop structure)

I narrowed the problem down to an issue when mixing types:

```
def iterGet(df,col):
    for i in df.index:
        tmp = df[col].loc[i]

def iterLocSet(df,col,val):
    for i in df.index:
        #df[col].loc[i] = val
        df.loc[i,col] = val
        df.at[i,col] = val
return df

N = 100
df = pd.DataFrame(rand(N,3),columns = ['a','b','c'])

df['listCol'] = [[] for i in range(df.shape[0])]
df['strCol'] = [str(i) for i in range(df.shape[0])]
df['intCol'] = [i for i in range(df.shape[0])]
df['float64Col'] = [float64(i) for i in range(df.shape[0])]

print df.a[:5]

%time iterGet(df[['a','intCol']].copy(),'a')
%time tmpDf = iterLocSet(df[['a','intCol']].copy(),'a',0.)
print tmpDf.a[:5]

%time iterGet(df[['a','float64Col']].copy(),'a')
%time tmpDf = iterLocSet(df[['a','float64Col']].copy(),'a',0.)
print tmpDf.a[:5]
```

On Pandas 0.15.1 the result is:

```
0    0.114738
1    0.586447
2    0.296024
3    0.446697
4    0.720984
Name: a, dtype: float64
Wall time: 6 ms
Wall time: 3.41 s
0    0
1    0
2    0
3    0
4    0
Name: a, dtype: float64
Wall time: 6 ms
Wall time: 18 ms
0    0
1    0
2    0
3    0
4    0
Name: a, dtype: float64
```

But on Pandas 0.13.1 the result is this:

```
0    0.651796
1    0.738661
2    0.885366
3    0.513006
4    0.846323
Name: a, dtype: float64
Wall time: 6 ms
Wall time: 14 ms
0    0
1    0
2    0
3    0
4    0
Name: a, dtype: float64
Wall time: 5 ms
Wall time: 15 ms
0    0
1    0
2    0
3    0
4    0
Name: a, dtype: float6
```

It appears that making an assignment using row-indexing on a multi-typed array is ~200x slower in Pandas 0.15.1?

I am aware there may be a potential pitfall here by assigning to what may be a copy of the array, but I admit I do not fully understand that issue either. Here at least I can see the assignment is working. *EDIT* Although I see now that using either of these in the for loop fixes the problem:

```
df.loc[i,col] = val
df.at[i,col] = val
```

I don't know enough about the implementation to diagnose this. Can anyone reproduce this? Is this what you would expect? What am I doing wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: What are `iterGet` and `iterLocSet`?

Comment: You might want to look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22869893/assign-value-to-subset-of-rows-in-pandas-dataframe).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `.loc` even on a single-dtyped frame, *can* cause a copy of the data on a partial assignment. (This is almost always true when you have *object* dtypes, less so with numeric types).

When partial assignment, I mean:

```
df.loc[1,'B'] = value
```

IOW. this is setting a single value in this case (setting multiple values is similar). However setting a *column* is very different.

```
df['B'] = values
df[:,'B'] = values
```

is quite efficient and does not copy.

Thus you should completely avoid iteration and simply do.

```
df['B'] = [ ..... ]  # if you want to set with a list-like
df['B'] = value # for a scalar
```

So in your above example, it is likely copying at every iteration. 0.13.1 was a bit buggy in handling partial assignments and would incorrectly handle certain cases, so copying was needed a bit more.

Comment: So the recommended solution is to make a single copy of a column that needs to be edited and then copy it back into the df after editing is complete? I would like to know what is wrong with <code> df[col].loc[i] = val </code>. Also, note that 0.13.1 may have been "buggy" but in this case it was correct and efficient.

Comment: Ok I think I see. `df[col].loc[i] = val` is probably making a copy of the entire column for each assignment and `df.loc[i,col] = val' doesn't (and this behavior must have changed in 0.15). Thanks!

Comment: so ``df[col].loc[i]`` is *chained assignment*. It *can* work, but in a mixed-dtype frame will usually not (and that's the rub, it should either always or never work, but it is dependent on if a view happens). That's why copying happens more often. Still you should almost never actually set things in a loop. Much more efficient not to.