# Chained assigment in pandas to modify cell value

Tags: python, pandas

I have two Dataframes, one contains connection points (Busdata) and the other units (Gendata). I am trying to assign the connection point to the corresponding units.

Busdata

```
Index Time  ID   Generators   Loads
0       0  'n1'    ['G1']    []
1       0  'n2'    []        ['D1']
2       0  'n3'    ['G2']    ['D2']
```

Gendata as I have it now

```
Index Time  ID     Type   Bus
0       0  'G1'    'DG'   
1       0  'G2'    'DG'
```

Gendata as I want it

```
Index Time  ID     Type   Bus
0       0  'G1'    'DG'   'n1'
1       0  'G2'    'DG'   'n3'
```

For what I read in [other posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22869893/assign-value-to-subset-of-rows-in-pandas-dataframe) I am having a chain indexing problem, but I have no clue how to solve it.

```
for t in time: #for each time step   
    for gen in Gendata.loc[Gendata['Time']==t].ID: #for each generator ID (G1, G2, etc)
        for bus in Busdata.loc[Busdata['Time']==t].ID: #for each node (n1, n2, n3, etc)
            if gen in Busdata.loc[Busdata['Time']==t].loc[Busdata['ID']==bus]['Generators']: 
               #if the generator is connected to that node, then I want to add the bus name to the Bus colum
               #so I am using this, but it sets the modification in a copy, thus the change never actually happens
               Gendata.loc[Gendata['Time']==t].loc[Gendata['ID']==gen]['Bus'].iloc[0]=bus
```

The idea is to select a cell in the dataframe based on the time, the generator ID and then modify the Bus column

Comment: gendata as you have it and gendata as you want it is the same? Am I missing something?

Comment: You are right, I made a mistake, now you can see how the column Bus is empty

Comment: Maybe I'm missing sth obvious but can't you do something like `Gendata.merge(Busdata[['Index', 'Time', 'ID']], on=['Index', 'Time'], how='left').rename(columns={'ID': 'Bus'})`?

Comment: I am not so sure what you are trying to do... Index by the way is not a column, but the df.index values. Your code returns an error related to this

Comment: Okay I got your point. I moved G2 around so you can see what I try to do